# Cocoa animations using CATransition in a single view

Tags: cocoa, macos, animation

I want to use `CATransition` to provide a fading animation between different states of a view.  However, this doesn't seem to work with a single view (all examples I found use `CATransition` to switch between different views).  In contrast, a `CABasicAnimation` works just fine.

My [example code](http://github.com/jjk/TestTransitions) shows what I'm doing.  I have a custom view (`TTView`) with two properties I want to animate.  One is a color, animated using `CABasicAnimation` (simple interpolation).  The other is a boolean state, and I want to achieve a fading effect when it changes.  (Ignore the fact that the example uses it to just change a rectangle's size, that's just to keep it simple.)

Am I doing something wrong, or does `CATransition` just not work within a single view?

Comment: Can you please paste the relevant code in your question?  The link to the repository isn't direct enough.

Answer (score 0):

The code is a bit large, but here are the most relevant parts of the `TTView` implementation.  The `scale` property is the boolean value whose change I want to animate with a transition.

```
+ (id) defaultAnimationForKey: (NSString *)key
{
  if ([key isEqualToString: @"color"]) {
    return [CABasicAnimation animation];

  } else if ([key isEqualToString: @"scale"]) {
    return [CATransition animation];
  }

  return [super defaultAnimationForKey:key];
}

/* ... */

- (IBAction) toggleScale: (id)sender
{
  [[self animator] setScale: !self.scale];
}
```

I just noticed that `CATransition` is not a subclass of `CAPropertyAnimation`, so perhaps that's my real problem.